# Details from a tuple to be displayed on a web page using Jinja2

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, jinja2

I am writing a script in python which will fetch details of On Demand assets from my server. Currently I am fetching Title, Poster and Rating of the Asset. I can get those details into a named tuple. From there I need to print including the display of the poster on a web page using Jinja2. I am not sure what I am missing here. The code I wrote is

**Test.py**

```
import requests
from collections import namedtuple
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

r = requests.get("http://172.19.37.3:5600/cmdc/content?region=24802&currency=myr&catalogueId=24802&isPurchasable&filter=source~vod&filter=source~group&count=255&collapse=true&sort=%2btitle&pset=Group1")

data = r.json()
assets = {}
AssetDetails = namedtuple('AssetDetails', 'title, parental_rating, poster_uri')

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template('test.html')

for asset in data['contents']:
    for media_uri in asset['media']:
        poster_uri = ""
        if media_uri['classification'] == "urn:nnds:Metro:metadata:MediaTypeCS:2007:2.1":
            poster_uri = media_uri['uri']

        assets[asset['id']] = AssetDetails(asset['title'], asset['parentalRating']['rating'], poster_uri)
        #print assets[asset['id']]
        if poster_uri != "":
           print " ".join(('Title:', assets[asset['id']].title))
           print " ".join(('Parental_Rating:', str(assets[asset['id']].parental_rating)))
           print " ".join(('Poster_uri:', assets[asset['id']].poster_uri))
```

**templates/test.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for item in c['assets']: %}
   <h1>{{ items['title'] }}</h1>
   <ul>
    <img src="{{ item['poster_uri'] }}" />
    <li>Id: {{ item['parentalRating'] }} </li>
   </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Or is there any other way to get these details on a web page? I know I am not populating a web page to get these details but I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Where's the rest of that test, where it actually renders the template? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Dan.. This is where my doubt is. How can i render the template?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what your question is. You render it in exactly the same way as any other template, with the `render` method - see the [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/).

Comment: Dan.. This is the first time I am using Django. When i looked another example the command to render is 
    output_from_parsed_template = template.render(foo='Hello World!')    But how can i render this particular test.html? I hope it's clear now.

Comment: This isn't Django, it's Jinja2. Why can't you use that exact method here?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It's Jinja2. I need to pass a lot of variables into the HTML. I am confused in doing that.

Comment: Dan.. i am changing my code. I can see some progress. Please help me if i am stuck.

Comment: Dan..I found the solution. But there is a problem with the display of images. Should I ask another question for this?

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code in the test.py. Removed namedtuple and used a list of lists to get the values extracted. Passed the list to the html file while rendering.

**test.py**

```
import requests, re
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
r = requests.get("http://172.19.37.3:5600/cmdc/content?region=24802&currency=myr&catalogueId=24802&isPurchasable&filter=source~vod&filter=source~group&count=30&collapse=true&sort=%2btitle&pset=Group1")

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template('test.html')
data = r.json()
assets = list()

for asset in data['contents']:
    for media_uri in asset['media']:
        poster_uri = ""
        if media_uri['classification'] == "urn:nnds:Metro:metadata:MediaTypeCS:2007:2.1":
            poster_uri = media_uri['uri']
            a_id = (asset['id'])
            id = a_id[a_id.index('://') + 3:]
            a_id = id
            asset_id = a_id.encode('utf-8')
            asset_title = asset['title'].encode('utf-8')
            asset = [asset_id, asset_title, poster_uri]
            assets.append(asset)
            poster_uri = poster_uri.encode('utf-8')

templateVars = { "VOD" : assets }

outputText = template.render( templateVars )
with open("VOD_Parsing.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(outputText)
```

**test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div id="content">
   {% for item in VOD %}
      <li>ID: {{ item[0] }}</li><li> Title: {{ item[1] }}</b></li>
      <img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```